# R filter by contains substring multiple conditions

Tags: r

Hey I have a list 500K rows that I need to filter by a condition where it must contains certain substrings (another list of 20 substrings).

I am using `dplyr` package right now and my code looks like this:

```
result <- data %>% 
          filter( grepl('sub1', column1) ||
                  grepl('sub2', column1) ||
                  grepl('sub3', column1) ||
                  grepl('sub4', column1) ||
                  ...
                  grepl('sub20', column1))
```

This whole thing is really killing me as the second list get longer, I am wondering is there an easy(or shorter?) way of doing this.

Comment: Can you try `filter(grepl(paste(paste0('sub', 1:20), collapse="|"), column1))`

Comment: @akrun, that is wonderful, so you are building a regular expression pattern "sub1|sub2..|sub20" to pass it to that function filter. Smart!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `paste` the pattern strings together and `collapse` it by `|`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
     filter(grepl(paste(paste0('sub', 1:20), collapse="|"), column1))
```